# Use lftp to compare remote directory without executing transfer

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, lftp

Rsync is unavailable on my system.  I need to compare two sites using lftp without executing the transfer (just like -n using rsync).

Comment: You could run `ls -lR` on both sites and compare the results.  The comparison might not be trivial (or even possible) if the two sites return `NLST` results in different formats.  There isn't much you can do to address that.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `mirror` with `--dry-run`.